# How to avoid code duplication in a render() function in Shiny for R

Tags: r, function, shiny

I am new to Shiny, so excuse if this is trivial...

I have a server() function that outputs several plots. The plots use the same block of code and each adds some of its own, like this:

```
shinyServer( function( input, output ){
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  the block of the same code
  some code specific to plot1
})
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  The block of the same code
  some code specific to plot2
})
```

I want to avoid repeating "the block of the same code". This has to be in the renderPlot function since it takes changeable data from the UI function.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to put the block into a "reactive" - like a function, but it reacts to changes.

```
shinyServer( function( input, output ){
  basicplot = reactive({
                 the block of the same code
              })
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  plot1 = basicplot()
  some code specific to plot1
})
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
  plot2 = basicplot()
  some code specific to plot2
})
```

the "basicplot" reactive is basically a function that outputs whatever it is that the plot1 and plot2 specific parts need to work on.

Comment: Thanks. I also listened to the video on reactive. Just what I needed.

Comment: I would add that you only need to make `basicplot` reactive if it draws on any of the inputs. If it is independent of inputs, then it should be a traditional function.